# Best way to control the ggplot size

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I was wondering how I can modify the below code to control the size of the plot (Forexample: How I can bring y elements more close to each other to make the plot smaller)

```
Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)

library(dplyr)  
Data <- group_by(Data,Year) %>%
 mutate(pos = cumsum(Frequency) - (0.5 * Frequency))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Frequency, y = pos), size = 3, nudge_y = -25) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Category, y = pos), size = 3, nudge_y = 25)
```

Comment: You can adjust plot size when you save the plot to a file. Check out `?ggsave`, particularly the `width` and `height` arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you are just trying to save the plot at specific dimensions, then you can just export the plot as a pdf like this:

```
 pdf("C:/mypdf.pdf", width=5, height=5)
 p
 dev.off()
```

If your intention is to remove white space and make the used plot area smaller, you can specify a specific width for you bars to remove space between bars, expand the scale to the edges of the plot, remove the plot margin (library grid is required), and move the legend inside the plot:

```
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency)) +
     geom_bar(aes(fill = Category,width=.95), stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
     geom_text(aes(label = Frequency, y = pos), size = 3, nudge_y = -25) +
     geom_text(aes(label = Category, y = pos), size = 3, nudge_y = 25) +
     theme( plot.margin = unit( c(0,0,0,0) , "in" ) ) +
     scale_x_discrete( expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
     theme(legend.position=c(1,1),legend.justification=c(1, 1),legend.box.just="left")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. I am going to bring all the plots into world format for my report and sometimes I have several plots in a page, I am looking for a way to have a  better visualization and quality.

Answer (score 2):

try the cowplot package to scale plots in a drawing window

```
library(cowplot)
ggdraw()+draw_plot(p,x=0,y=0,width=.5,height = .5)
```